# При обновление страницы весь `.append()` исчезает

Tags: javascript, jquery

Объясните, пожалуйста.

Как добавить элемент на страницу через `.append()`, но так, чтобы при обновление страницы добавленный элемент не исчезал?

```
$('#button').on('click', function(){
    $('body').append('<p>test</p>')
});
```

Comment: Ну минимум localStorage или же база данных

Answer (score 1):

Раз уж вы заюзали jQuery, то кода будет поменьше. Я соглашусь с комментарием про `localStorage` или БД, однако ответа я не увидел, поэтому покажу идею с `localStorage`, на мой взгляд этот подход более простой. Дополним метод клика:

```
$('#button').on('click', function(){
    const element = '<p>test</p>'; // положили в переменную наш элемент
    $('body').append(element); // дабавили к body наш элемент
    const items = localStorage.getItem('appended'); // получили по ключу свой элемент
    var elements = JSON.parse(items) || []; // распарсили полученный элемент
    elements.push(element); // добавили в массив
    localStorage.setItem('appended', JSON.stringify(elements)); // записали новое значение
});
```

А также добавим блок кода, который будет добавлять элементы после того, как страница обновилась:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    const items = localStorage.getItem('appended'); // получили по ключу свой элемент
    var elements = JSON.parse(items) || []; // распарсили полученный элемент
    // пройдем по элементам и добавим их к body
    for (var index = 0; index < elements.length; index++) {
       $('body').append(elements[index]); // дабавили к body наш элемент
    }
});
```

Полезные ссылки:

- [Window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)
- [Storage.setItem()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem)
- [Storage.getItem()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem)
- [Storage.removeItem()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Storage/removeItem)
- [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)
- [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Answer (score 0):

Использовать [куки](https://ruseller.com/lessons.php?id=593)

**Статические решение:**
Изначально скрывать данный блок до поры до времени, а потом по клику показывать? В куки клиенту прописывать, что данный блок уже видимый и при повторном показе показывать сразу.

**Динамическое решение:** В том виде как это сделано у вас куки можно использовать для того чтобы сохранить какие блоки показаны, а какие скрыты и при обновлении страницы, прочитав куки, динамически добавлять/удалять соответствующие блоки.